# SQL Server DateTime型と文字列の比較方法について

Tags: c#, sql-server

c#でSQL serverのテーブルにデータを登録する処理を作成中です。
登録の際にファイルから読み込んだ日時とDateTime型の列に秒まで指定して登録しますが、再び同じ日時のデータを登録する場合は日時をキーにUpdateしたいです。

しかし、SQL serverでの日時の比較時にCONVERT関数を利用するとインデックスがきかなくなるということなので、このような場合は日時をDatetime型ではなくvarchar等の文字列で登録するほうが良いのではと考えております。
Datetime型と文字列の日時をインデックスが有効になる形で一致検索する方法はありますでしょうか？

このあたり何かノウハウがありましたらご教示頂きたく宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: インデックスが効かないことに何か問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 具体的なコードが有ると回答しやすいと思います。C#からクエリを投げるんであれば普通にパラメタライズドクエリで良いと思うんですが。

Comment: 大量のデータを登録するためインデックスがきかなくなるのは困ります。

Comment: パラメーター指定すればDatetime型で一致検索できるんですね！秒未満は指定しませんが指定しない場合はミリ秒は000になるのでしょうか。

Comment: なぜ秒まで格納するのか、なぜ日時で検索するのか、質問者にしかわからないことだらけで、答えようがない質問です。秒を使わないなら格納しなければいいですし、`convert`を使わなくても範囲指定で検索すればインデックスは有効ですし。XY問題に陥っていませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CONVERT`関数](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)を使用すれば効率的な検索ができなくなるのは当然の結果です。しかし日時をキーに検索するだけであれば[`DATEADD`関数](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)を使って

```
WHERE @inputdate <= DatetimeColumn AND DatetimeColumn < DATEADD(minute, 1, @inputdate)
```

のように必要な範囲を指定すれば効率的に検索できます。

そもそも[`smalldatetime`型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)を使えば4バイトで済む内容です。[`varchar`型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)を使用する場合`2018/12/14 08:11:00`と格納するつもりでしょうか、この場合19+2バイト必要になります。更にC#から文字列を扱う場合すべてUnicodeとなるため、Unicode→MBCS変換も発生します。[`nvarchar`型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)を使えば変換は排除できますが、今度は38+2バイトに膨れ上がります。いずれにしても大量のデータを登録するのであればこの差は非常に大きな問題となります。

また「インデックスが効かない」という表現も不明確です。`CONVERT`関数を使用したとしても参照するカラムが適切であればインデックスは常に有効です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。日時は、varcharの場合、yyyyMMddhhmmssで登録します。他のキーだけではユニークキーにならないため、秒まで記載されているファイルの日時データもユニークキーの一つになります。登録した後、この日時もキーにして登録した情報を読み出したいのです。そのため、指定した日時（ファイルから読み込みyyyyMMddhhmmss形式のデータ）と完全一致したデータを読み出したいです。

Comment: インデックスの有効性についてはwhere CONVERT（DatetimeColumn）=　inputdateの用に検索した場合にindex seekにならないという意味となります。